# How can we change message of inbuilt annotation provided by java at run time

Tags: java, annotations

How can we change message of in built annotation provided by java at run time?

There are links which talk about changing the message of custom annotation : e.g [Can you change an annotation message at run time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048556/can-you-change-an-annotation-message-at-run-time)

Above link  helped me to solve my one problem.

But I want to know how to do this for the annotations provide by Java itself.

e.g

```
@DefaultValue

@Digit

@Min
```

I can use something like

@Min(value = 1, message = "Value must be 1 or more")

but this is static message, is there any way to make it dynamic.

-Cheers

Comment: Get the source code of the annotaion, overwrite it with your changes, use the new annotation.

Comment: It is not the annotation per se that determines the message, it is the one doing the validating. What are you using? Hibernate?

Comment: I am using Spring. want to use spring Property loading to get the message from properties file and then use that for displaying the messages into annotation.