# How to define an error message inside a custom @annotation

Tags: java, validation

I'm building my own `@annotation` that valids many fields of a class (so it's a class level annotation and not a field level annotation).

When there is an error I add a `ConstraintViolation` and I print an error message taken from .properties file. The error is something like :
*The field **{1}** must be less than the field **{2}***

What I need is the way to fill the variables **{1}** and **{2}** . And I have to do it inside the method `isValid()`, since is there  that I dinamically define what are values to show inside the error message in place of **{1}** and **{2}**

This is my annotations:

```
@EsempioAnnotationClassLevel(dateFromNomeCampo={"dataDiNascitaFrom","dataLavoroFrom",...})
```

This is my interface:

```
    @Constraint(validatedBy = EsempioAnnotationClassLevelValidator.class)
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Target(ElementType.TYPE)
    public @interface EsempioAnnotationClassLevel  {        
        String[] dateFromNomeCampo();
        String message() default "Errore FatherSearchInterface;         
        Class<?>[] groups() default {};         
        Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {}; 
}
```

this is my class that implements `ConstraintValidator`:

```
public class EsempioAnnotationClassLevelValidator implements ConstraintValidator<EsempioAnnotationClassLevel, Object>{
...
 public boolean isValid(Object object, ConstraintValidatorContext cxt) { 
    ...
    cxt.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("errorMessage").addNode("field").addConstraintViolation();
    ...   
 }
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check if the following question can help as reference?

[Can you change an annotation message at run time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048556/can-you-change-an-annotation-message-at-run-time)

Comment: Unfortunately not, the problem discussed in that post is different from mine (my code already solved the problem discussed in that post).